# Ag-grid Collapsible Columns in Pivot Mode

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-ng2

In ag-grid I'm trying to use column grouping in pivot mode.

E.g. In the plunker in the below link, a 'sum(Total)' column is displayed after setting gridOptions.pivotColumnGroupTotals = 'before'. Instead of this I would want the 'Gold' column to be displayed by default, and when the column group is expanded 'Silver' and 'Bronze' columns should be displayed along with 'Gold' column.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-pivoting/#pivotColumnGroupTotals

ag-grid has an option to achieve this in non-pivot grids using the column property 'columnGroupShow' as in below link. But not sure how to achieve the same in pivot grids.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/

Appreciate any help!

Comment: @niall-crosby Appreciate any help! :)